# How to remove compiler error with struct: "Use of unassigned local variable"

Tags: c#, struct, mono

The C# compiler is a bit ... old fashioned ... and won't do static analysis. So it breaks on *seemingly* correct code like this:

```
MyStruct s;
bool inited = false;
foreach( Something foo in ACollection )
{
  if( foo.Test() )
    continue;
  if( inited )
    s.DoSomething();
  else
  {
    s = foo.GetMeAnS();
    inited = true;
  }
}
```

*Note: the unusual problem is that "s" is a struct. If it were a class, I'd simply init it to null. This struct has no meaningful "uninited" state, and I don't want to pay the performance cost of initing something I immediately throw away, just to satisfy a weak compiler.*

The code (should be) fully correct: it's impossible to access s until s has been inited. (I've copy/pasted from actual code, but edited-out long method names for simplicity).

C# compiler in Mono used to allow this, but now it doesn't. Nothing has changed except the compiler, which now gives an error on unassigned variable.

Is there a code way to tell it to shut up and mind its own business? :) I don't want to fiddle with changing compiler-settings (if possible) because the code is compiled by other people/orgs - I'd prefer a code way of fixing the problem.

Comment: Why not simply: `foreach(Something foo in ACollection.Where(f => !f.Test()))
            {
                MyStruct s = foo.GetMeAnS();
            }` This removes most of the code and is still doing the same. You don't need to declare it outside of the loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter There's a variation where s aggregates data on each successive match within the collection - so "s.DoSomething()" becomes "s.DoSomething( foo )". The code was written to do a single init - lazily, nothing init'd if not needed, and return something if init'd, return something different if never init'd.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ...but I think it's OK to have the code diverge. I'm going to rewrite the two to work differently - and see if I can do something like re-use an existing instance of the struct, or just give up and init it anyway - like JonSkeet says, it might be fine at runtime anyway :) or it might be good-enough in this situation that I can take the hit.

Comment: As far as I can tell the OP is asking why the compiler hasn't solved the halting problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a code way to tell it to shut up and mind its own business?

The compiler's business is implementing the C# specification. The code you've written *should not* compile according to the C# specification. The `s.DoSomething()` call is reachable without `s` being definitely assigned, therefore your code is broken. That's not the compiler's fault. If the Mono compiler *used* to allow it, that was a bug which has apparently now been fixed.

The simplest way of fixing it is to definitely assign the value, of course:

```
MyStruct s = new MyStruct(); // Value will never actually be used
```

There are plenty of cases where we (as humans) can tell that something will never happen, but the compiler can't. Here's another example:

```
public int Foo(int input)
{
    if (input >= 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else if (input < 0)
    {
        return -input;
    }
    // This is still reachable...
}
```

*We* know that every `int` input will go into one of those `if` bodies, but the compiler will still (correctly) give a compilation error on the above code, because the closing brace is reachable and it's a non-void method.

Your claim that "The code (should be) fully correct" is according to your reasoning, not the C# specificiation... and the compiler is only meant to care about the latter.

One thing to note: the specification doesn't even care about the fact that we do actually set `inited` to true in some cases. Even if it *always* had the value of `false`, it's still just a local variable, not a constant expression. Here's a simple example demonstrating that with no loop:

```
static void Main()
{
    int x;
    bool condition = false;
    if (condition)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

This still gives an error: "error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'x'"

From section 8.7.1 of the C# 5 specification:

> The first embedded statement of an `if` statement is reachable if the if statement is reachable and the boolean expression does not have the constant value `false`.

Here the expression is `condition`, which is a local variable. A local variable is *not* a constant expression in technical terms, even if it will never change. If you make it a local constant instead, it *will* compile:

```
static void Main()
{
    int x;
    const bool condition = false;
    if (condition)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Now there's a *warning* about the body of the `if` statement being unreachable - but there's no error.

Comment: But it compiles in VS 2010. `s.DoSomething()` is not reachable with this code, is it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It shouldn't compile if `MyStruct` has any fields. How would you claim that `s.DoSomething()` isn't reachable, bearing in mind that `inited` is a variable? The body of any `if` statement is reachable unless the condition is a *constant expression* with a value of `false`.

Comment: @jon - "The s.DoSomething() call is reachable without s being definitely assigned" - really? How? The code was written specifically to guarantee that would never happen. Maybe I'm blind today *and* the compiler used to have a bug, but I'm not seeing a situation where it could happen :(. If there is - my bad!

Comment: Because `inited` is never true and will not change. It will be `true` when `s` wil be initialized.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That doesn't matter - it's a variable.

Comment: @JonSkeet: but a local value type variable which cannot be modified here apart from in the `else` block

Comment: @Adam: I'm talking in the terms of the specification... not in terms of whether in reality you could ever get in there without having assigned a value to `s`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That doesn't matter. From the C# 5 specification: "The first embedded statement of an `if` statement is reachable if the `if` statement is reachable and the boolean expression does not have the constant value `false`." The boolean expression is a regular local variable. The spec doesn't say anything about a local variable which would only have a particular value being a constant. When you say you've got this working in VS2010, is that in a short but complete example? If so, does your `MyStruct` struct have any fields?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the ref - I had no idea the spec defined that (and it seems a bizarre definition). Is this specifically so that compilers don't have to do static analysis? Is there some other reason? And ... given the spec is written this way, it would seem there is strong need for a directive/something that lets programmers say "no, you are wrong. If you were to analyse the syntax in more detail, you'd see it. I have. Trust me. Please!"

Comment: @Adam: I disagree. I think it's important that a) the compiler does provide protection for this sort of thing; b) the specification is kept reasonably sane. I'm currently involved in the ECMA standardization of C# 5, and formulating precise rules for this sort of thing *even with them being as restrictive as they are* is really difficult. Trying to do it accurately - and in such a way that *every compiler will behave the same way* with a lot more complex rules would be an absolute nightmare. I'm glad C# is specced this way.

Comment: @jonskeet - protection, yes, I love that part. I'm all in favor! But directly contradicting the syntax - saying that a codeblock that logically CANNOT be entered is, in fact, entered - is sufficiently incorrect that I'd hope for / expect some workaround?

Comment: @JonSkeet: but then i wonder why it was allowed in C#4. I only have VS2010 here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It shouldn't be, *if* the compiler knows that `MyStruct` has fields. Can you put up a gist with a short but complete example that compiles for you?

Comment: Also, I had no idea this would turn out to be so interesting - I thought there was some 1-shot solution I was missing (that didn't involve artificailly init'ing structs; performance here is a real issue - we're avoiding unnecessary inits inside tight loops in games). If there's a better place I should go to read/discuss/contest this, please point me at it.

Comment: @Adam: Is the artificial initialization *actually* an issue here? Have you tried it? Because I would expect the JIT to quite possibly be able to remove it, if it zeroes memory on the stack on entry to the method.

Comment: @JonSkeet for this case, I'm not sure - but the main deployment target is Unity3D, which is locked on an old version of Mono (allegedly because Xamarin wouldn't license newer versions except at huge cost) - and when I've run this analysis on other code blocks, runtime optimizations have been disappointingly weak. I am only vaguely aware of the politics, but there's a million odd Unity devs who are stuck in this situation.

Comment: Isn't this related to the halting problem. If we replace halting with init, then we are asking the compiler in general, does this algorithm halt?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Your example struct doesn't have any fields and hence cannot be uninitialized. Add a field and it will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The C# specification was designed such that you should never be able to use an uninitialized variable. This is not an old fashioned concept. The old fashioned way to deal with this (in C++) was to say, "This is undefined behaviour, anything can happen".

Strangely enough lots of bugs were caused by this attitude, which gave rise to many compilers automagically initing (in debug mode) variables into such gems as 0xDEADBEEF.

As for why the C# compiler doesn't do code analysis to find if the variable is inited when it reaches that code?

## Halting Problem

The problem could be rewritten like this.

```
bool inited = false;
MyStruct? s;    

while (true)
{
   foreach( Something foo in ACollection )
      foo.Test();
   if( inited && false == s.HasValue )
      return;
}
```

This is only slightly changed code. But you can see, I have converted your problem into the Halting Problem, where the inputs are, the state of each `Something` and the implementation of `foo.Test()`.

This is proven to be undecidable on a Turing Machine, which your CLR VM certainly is.

In short, you are asking, why hasn't microsoft broken the laws of Mathematics and Computer Science when they wrote the C# compiler.

Or you are asking, shouldn't the Microsoft C# Compiler try hard before giving up on the Halting Problem. To which my response is, how hard should they try?

Comment: No. c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis - Halting Problem shouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: @Adam I understand that. In most cases one can side the halting problem. However the OP has not included the code to `foo.Test()`. This says to me that he expects that the C# compiler should search all possible    code paths, which IS the halting problem. My point was that the C# compiler writers choose to search only a limited number of code paths, to sidestep the Halting Problem.

Comment: As Tim pointed out - this is a simple, common case piece of code: use a locally evaluated boolean variable to decide which code paths can be followed. The other modern compilers I'm used to (Objective-C, Java - but not c#?) seem to do this particular (kind of) check routinely.